# No internet connectivity in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, vmware

**Issue:**
No network connectivity on ubuntu VM  through wired connection.Cant use WIFI.

I tried this question([Can't connect to a network at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555481/cant-connect-to-a-network-at-all)) and started troubleshooting with this one ([Can't connect to a network at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555481/cant-connect-to-a-network-at-all))..

below is some info which may help you.I tried to solve this for more than 2 days.but no luck

**IP of host :**
[image]

**vmware settings:**
[image]

**ifconfig:**
[image]

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

**ubuntu screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

things done so far with out any success
1.restart of network manager
2.changed from nat to bridged and vice versa
3.mac address changed to ens33

**What worked :**
changing from vmware work station to vmware player worked

Comment: Have you tried in bridged mode?

Comment: let me try now and update the question

Comment: same issue even after changing to bridged

Comment: Does the MAC addr in your `ifconfig` match the MAC addr provided by your virtualisation software? Looking at your screen for network adapter settings, should be in 'Advanced', if you're using VMware like I suspect.

Comment: Are you sure your wireless adapter is not broken?

Comment: You meant my physical NIC

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is broken routing somewhere. First, make sure you have connectivity on your windows host.

Sounds dumb but if this is a new install I would restart your computer and make sure all the needed processes for VMware are running.

I think your configuration should work (and that you might want to use NAT instead of bridge mode since your host is Windows, but I'm not too familiar with VMware) but for some reason VMware DHCP server is not enabled/running on the NAT interface (that's why I said reboot and check everything is running) or your vm is not linked to the NAT interface.

Could you provide the output on the host for:
`ipconfig /all`
`route print`
Could you provide the output on the guest vm for:
`cat /etc/resolv.conf`
`ip a s`
`ip r`

Comment: My Ubuntu VMs work fine but I use KVM on a Linux host. I have used both bridging and NAT, but if you use bridging then you need to take care of the routing and the NATing if accessing the Internet so traffic can reach back to your birdge from the Internet.

Comment: `ipconfig /all` would let us know if the MAC address matches or are similar on both the host and the guest, but I'm not sure on how this is implemented in VMware.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Another option would be to run the following two commands (start this one first) `tcpdump -i ens33 host 8.8.8.8` and (start this one second) `tracepath 8.8.8.8` and share the output. The idea is to trouble shoot the net routing wise. Then we would do dns.

Comment: @TheGameiswar If you have a tunnel running do `ping 8.8.8.8` instead of  `tracepath 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, I fixed it by changing the **Network Adapter type** from NAT to **Bridged Adapter**

**edit**

Please choose the adapter with network connection ie( if you are connected with wifi use wlan for bridged adapter) and it should work

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: The op says he already did this...

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: The op says he already did this (changing the network adapter type from nat to bridged adapter)

Comment: Yes but choosing the right network interface also plays a part.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this will work, you may have to experiment a bit,
First under the Ethernet Tab you need to select a device.
Under the IPV4 Tab you need to select
(Automatic)DHCP Addresses Only
have set mine to the google DNS
DNS Servers:8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

And you may also have to set it to Bridged....